# Google Maps: ReferenceError: google is not defined

Tags: reference, defined

Whenever i try to load the google maps html code i never get anything to display and i get the following error:

ReferenceError: google is not defined

I can create a hyperlink to google maps but this isn't what i want. I also went ahead and got my own API key and put it into my code. Why isn't google defined? This seems too common of a problem to not have a solution.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My first Google Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
        html {
            height: 100%;
        }

        body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #map-canvas {
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDX71YSt1efYJH3MdIsH3SF3kyJNjN-Z78&amp;sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize() {
            var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(54.124634, -3.237029)
            var mapOptions = {
                center: myLatLng,
                zoom: 17,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
            };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
                mapOptions);

            var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatLng,
                map: map,
                title: "A place on Earth",
                draggable: true,
            })
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map-canvas" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Okay, after some serious computer science i was able to get rid of the error. However, i still cannot view anything on the page that is map or google related. What's wrong with the code to cause this?

Comment: I got it to finally work. I needed to say that my div for displaying the google map(s) had position: absolute. If you don't include position in your div then you get the default position of relative. A relative position won't work if you have multiple things on the screen or want to embed the map into a small div somewhere on the page.